# Android - check if a view is visible to the user

Tags: android, view, visibility

Say I have View A and View B as sibling views in my Android activity.
View B hides View A (for example, view B has a black background hiding view A)
They both have the exact same *dimensions* filling up the entire visible screen.

How can I check programmatically during runtime if view A is visible to the user?
I've tried isVisibleToUser, isVisible, isFocus, isShown etc which all don't work, since view A is set as visible, but due to the drawing order, is hidden by view B.

Comment: If you check for visibility of view B, and if it is true, it should be fair to say view A is hidden in your case, otherwise if view B's visibility is false, check if view A is visible, and if it is true, view A is visible, you can use this as a logic

Answer (score 0):

ok listen bro  for example you have two views
v1,v2;
this is a code to check if v1 is visible or not

```
if (v1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
{
 // if v1 is visible
}
else
{
// if v1 not visible
}
```

same check for v2

Comment: both return true.. any other ideas?

Comment: dear first you set visibility gone in xml and then set visible one of them in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 switch (view.getVisibility()){
        case View.VISIBLE:
            //The View is visible to the user.
            break;
        case View.INVISIBLE:
            //The view is not visible to the user but is still on the screen.
            break;
        case View.GONE:
            //The view is not visible to the user and is no longer on the screen.
            break;
    }
```

Comment: both return true.. any other ideas?

Comment: i guess you can make it such that the view you want to be hidden always has a lower elevation that the view that is hiding it.